# How to set textcolor of menu item in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to change text color of menu in mfc. I have searched a lot but didn't got a proper solution. Finally I was trying to use OnCtlColor which I generally use for setting the color of static text control. But I am confused here how to do the same for menu items because pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() dont work on menu.My menu item id is ID_MENU_ITEM. My query is what should i write at "?" to get my job done. And if my approach is wrong please suggest me good alternative.

```
HBRUSH CMyClass::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
  HBRUSH hbr;
  if (  ?  == ID_MENU_ITEM)
  {
    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    hbr = (HBRUSH)m_whitebrush;
    return hbr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is wrong. `OnCtlColor` is not called upon the drawing of a menu. You must user [owner draw menus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items).

Comment: For examples of ownerdraw menus look [here](http://cppandmfc.blogspot.ch/2012/12/mfc-creating-owner-draw-menu.html) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2354/Owner-Drawn-Menu-with-Icons-Titles-and-Shading).

Comment: This also depends on themes. I have an application that colors the menu based on a custom visual manager I implemented.

Comment: sir i have tried using owner drawn menu but text color is not changing in fact after calling ModifyMenu all the menu becomes grey.

Comment: Try to catch them on a function that handles **ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP()** and do recursively apply the customization to be owner drawn on every item. Or alternatively, assuming you are using the MFC Feature Pack, you can create your own theme. In my case I derived a class from **CMFCVisualManagerOfficeXP**. In the **OnFillBarBackground(...)** method override, I changed the **pDC->FillRect(...)** call's color parameter, just below the **if (pBarClass->IsDerivedFrom(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCPopupMenuBar))** line.